# Remove a number in a lis that does not appear in another list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, compare

I have two lists of numbers. In each are the numbers `[1,2,3,4]` but in one there is an extra fifth number eg.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to enforce that `list2` is the same as `list1`, by either removing the 5th number from `list2` or replacing `list2` with another copy of `list1`?

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to make sure `list2` is the same as `list1`? Can't you just use `list1`? I suspect there are additional constraints to your problem, which we need to know in order to help you.

Answer (score 8):

This question is worded a bit strangely. If you're looking to mutate one of the lists, then the answer is no: that is not possible. Otherwise, you can of course just use `list1` instead of `list2` anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 4):

`Data.List` provides the `intersect` method, which seems exactly what's being requested.

Comment: And if you are for some reason concerned about efficiency (and not concerned about preserving order or duplicates) then you can use `Data.Set.fromList` and `Data.Set.intersection`

Answer (score 3):

The most easy and performant way to enforce that `list2` is the same as `list1` would be to say

```
let list2 = list1 in .......
```

This would not even require that the list elements are comparable.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ x | x <- list1, x `elem` list2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

and here's another one though I like Louis_Wasserman's solution most

```
filter (`elem` [1..4]) [1..12]
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
filter (flip elem [1..4]) [1..12]
>>> [1,2,3,4]
fliter (\x ->x `elem` [1..4]) [1..12]
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

if list two is irrelevant why do you use it in the first place ??
and another one came to my mind:

```
const [1..4] list2
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

the last one just ignores the second list and fills in the first.